# Sublime Text 3 Python 3 input() won't submit

Tags: python-3.x, input, sublimetext3

```
x = input()
print (x)
```

I am trying to use `input()` in multiple functions but am having the same problem every time.  I remember only having to press enter in the past to submit my input when it prompts me to do so, however now, even once it prompts me to do so, I can't figure out how to submit my input and have the code continue.  This is REALLY frustrating and I have been searching everywhere with no answer.  There is never any error or response from python either, it just lets me type

TL,DR: I can't use `input()`, because when I do, sublime text lets me input forever and nothing I do will submit the text I wish to input.

Please try to explain in somewhat simple terms as I am relatively new to python and don't understand how to do things with the command line and paths and stuff like that very well.

Comment: I can't tell if it is a duplicate as I don't understand what is going on on that question.

Comment: You are likely using SublimeText's default build systems to execute your code.  The default systems do not support input or GUIs, so you have to customize your build systems as described in the duplicate thread. Another option is to use something like [**Console Exec**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Console%20Exec).